# How to set bootstrap in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, npm, bootstrap-4

in browser in console part shows the Error:

> GET http://localhost:8000/asset/app.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

then I tried to install boostrap using documentantion steps are.

```sh
1. composer require laravel/ui --dev. 
2. php artisan ui bootstrap.
3. php artisan ui bootstrap --auth.
4. npm install.
```

but here again in 4th Section it shows the Error and that the command not found. 
Still not working bootstrap

Comment: Question to be formatted..

Comment: Hey and welcome. To prevent your question to be closed (wrong formatting) or not to be answered, please read ["How do I ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit yours. Also, it is worth reading ["How to create a minimal reproducible example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are saying you are getting an error with the 4th command. I assume you do not have NPM installed.

Try installing NPM from here https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm. NPM is Node Package Manager. It will handle the front end dependencies for you. And is used to compile everything.

Also, after `npm install` run `npm run dev` to compile the javascript and such.

Comment: now npm install commmand is working after installing nodejs but again Errors              npm WARN tarball tarball data for glob@^7.1.2 (sha512-LwaxwyZ72Lk7vZINtNNrywX0ZuLyStrdDtabefZKAY5ZGJhVtgdznluResxNmPitE0SAO+O26sWTHeKSI2wMBA==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! syscall unlink

Comment: just restart the VS code and worked, Thank You so much You saved my hell of time

Answer (score 0):

Install node to enable npm. 
Also you can include bootstrap CDN directly in the  tag in your blades like a normal HTML project without installing it.

Here's how to add bootstrap CDN in your HTML file - Remember, blades are finally HTML files. 
[Bootstrap CDN](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/download/#bootstrapcdn)

Comment: I'm Sorry Long time not replied. Thank You so much for dear sister for mercy